# Format a date for PHP

Tags: php, string, date, time

I have a date:

> Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT

How can I convert that to this format:

> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

I have found something like this:

> $time = strtotime('10/16/2003');
>
> $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);

But how do I convert 'Mar' to '03', so I can use that?

Comment: Read [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: If your date format is *not* consistent: Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date string and create a DateTime object. And then format it with [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). The list of formats can be found in the [documentation here](http://php.net/date).

Comment: strtotime() is very flexible; have you tried just giving it your current string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime("Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT");

echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

No need, PHP's `strtotime` understands month names.

```
C:\Users\Niet>php
<?php
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT')));
^Z

string(19) "2014-03-31 12:19:10"
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` does the trick here too.

This code:

```
$date = 'Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT';
echo $date;
$time = strtotime('Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

will output this:

```
Mon, 31 Mar 2014 12:19:10 GMT
2014-03-31 14:19:10
```

**Note** that your **timezone** is important here too. I'm in GMT+2 timezone, so final hour is 14 instead of 12.